# NodeJS - Jimp - process a .png image to reduce it's weight (quality)

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I need to find the better way to process on a .png file to simply reduce it's quality.
In fact, I don't want to resize or apply filters on the image, just reduce the weight of the file (from 6mb to 1mb if possible).

If anyone knows the trick to do it, I'd be very grateful

Comment: So you want to reduce the size of a .png file without reducing it's quality or pixel-size?

Comment: Hey benSower, thank for the answer. No I'd like to do the opposite, don't reduce the size of the image, but the quality and (or?) pixel rate. the aim is just to reduce the weight of the file.

Comment: @HadrienDelphinhave you tried anything so far like https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/) serverside. Just make sure you're doing all the regular validation and parameterisation to prevent injection.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll give it a try! Thank for the tip!